# Explicit string behavior in non-constructor member functions

Tags: c++

I hope I've titled my question correctly.

I have a very large/old database with many non-null terminated char arrays and a few std::string types. I'm creating a tool that will use this database, and I'd like to ensure it's safety with respect to the non-null terminated char arrays. Ideally I'd like to support both types to make it easy for the developer to use the tool.

```
void AddCell( const std::string & _cell_str );
void AddCell( const char * _cell_data, size_t _array_size );
```

However, there's a specific scenario that could be problematic: if a new developer is unaware that the char array is non-null terminated and out of laziness decides to use the implicit conversion of the std::string because he doesn't have to enter the array size, then it's possible that the std::string will show some unwanted chars.

How can I deal with this problem? Should I force someone to specify the length of the std::string? Should I just remove the std::string overloaded function and make everyone use c_str() from their std::string? Ideally, I'd just use the explicit keyword, but it's only available for constructors. I'm hesitant to steer away from the use of std::string.

Comment: I'm missing something basic here. What is an implicit conversion of an std::string? are you referring to `AddCell("example");`?

Comment: @ahenderson, there's a constructor for `std::string` that takes a `char*` and isn't explicit.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks for the clarification. I still wish I had an example of the behavior they are trying to avoid.

Comment: This is clear to me now. If someones enters `text` where `const char text[]` then we have UB, if the array is not null terminated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the first overload so that instead of taking a std::string reference it takes a reference to a new type that you create that has an implicit conversion from std::string.  So you won't see the implicit conversion from const char*, but will take std::string with no problems.

Comment: This new type could also have a constructor that takes a `char` array and with some template magic automatically includes the array size. Then you'd only need one version of your member functions.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by an implicit conversion *from* an std::string? Do you simply mean that it should have a parameter that accepts a const std::string reference? In that case, wouldn't I still have the same problem as now? Shouldn't it be explicit?

Answer (score 6):

There are different things that can be done. One of them is `delete`-ing the `const char*` overload:

```
void AddCell(const std::string&);
void AddCell(const char*) = delete;
void AddCell(const char*,size_t);
```

Marking a function as `delete` triggers a compiler error on usage, but it does not remove it from the set of candidate functions for overloads. If the user passes a `const char*` the second overload will be picked up and the compiler will scream that the overload was deleted.

Of course, you can also provide a wrapper for arrays of know sizes so that they can safely and seamlessly pass literals:

```
template <size_t N>
void AddCell(const char (&array)[N]) {
   AddCell(array, N);
}
```

This allows for `AddCell("MyCell")`, as the literal is an array and the best candidate is the template, which will in turn dispatch to the `(const char*,size_t)` overload with the appropriate size.